# VS CODE - Facing issue with installing C/C++ extension pack

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-remote-ssh

I am trying to install C/C++ extension pack in ssh in VS code. Getting error as below. please help me on this.  Also I have tried to delete .vscode-server folder in the remote server. But not able to remove :  rm: cannot remove '.nfs000000006268700f00030561': Device or resource busy
I tried with "lsof +D .nfsXXXXXXXXX". help me to delete .vscode-server folder completely.

[2022-02-28 20:53:49.515] [renderer4] [error] ["Extract: Unknown system error -122: Unknown system error -122, close","    at i.extractAtLocation (/home/kbskd/.vscode-server/bin/f80445acd5a3dadef24aa209168452a3d97cc326/out/vs/server/node/server.main.js:143:83246)","    at async i.extractUserExtension (/home/kbskd/.vscode-server/bin/f80445acd5a3dadef24aa209168452a3d97cc326/out/vs/server/node/server.main.js:143:79977)","    at async L.extract (/home/kbskd/.vscode-server/bin/f80445acd5a3dadef24aa209168452a3d97cc326/out/vs/server/node/server.main.js:143:93663)"]
[2022-02-28 20:53:49.535] [renderer4] [error] ["Extract: Unknown system error -122: Unknown system error -122, close","    at i.extractAtLocation (/home/kbskd/.vscode-server/bin/f80445acd5a3dadef24aa209168452a3d97cc326/out/vs/server/node/server.main.js:143:83246)","    at async i.extractUserExtension (/home/kbskd/.vscode-server/bin/f80445acd5a3dadef24aa209168452a3d97cc326/out/vs/server/node/server.main.js:143:79977)","    at async L.extract (/home/kbskd/.vscode-server/bin/f80445acd5a3dadef24aa209168452a3d97cc326/out/vs/server/node/server.main.js:143:93663)"]
[2022-02-28 20:53:49.539] [renderer4] [error] Unknown system error -122: Unknown system error -122, close: Extract: Unknown system error -122: Unknown system error -122, close
at i.extractAtLocation (/home/kbskd/.vscode-server/bin/f80445acd5a3dadef24aa209168452a3d97cc326/out/vs/server/node/server.main.js:143:83246)
at async i.extractUserExtension (/home/kbskd/.vscode-server/bin/f80445acd5a3dadef24aa209168452a3d97cc326/out/vs/server/node/server.main.js:143:79977)
at async L.extract (/home/kbskd/.vscode-server/bin/f80445acd5a3dadef24aa209168452a3d97cc326/out/vs/server/node/server.main.js:143:93663)

Comment: Please think about filling an issue https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/new/choose

Comment: It is known that VSCode remote bits installation might fail if there is a quota on the default installation path. You can override the path via `remote.SSH.serverInstallPath`, and please read https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/472 for more details.

Answer (score -1):

The System error 122 is EDQUOT (Quota exceeded). Try to clean your Disk Quota.

> https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/7939